# Java EE WebService callback

Tags: c#, java, web-services, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

My C# program **sends a string to Java EE** and **continues sending others strings**.

Asynchronously, Java EE gets the string and returns true if the string is the word I need, the Java EE **needs to send something to C# (callback) to stop the process of sending others strings**.

Does anybody have a solution? I searched some examples but I found only callbacks for C# to C# or Java EE to Java EE only.

Comment: WebService as in SOAP service?

Comment: Yes like in SOAP service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but couldn't you open a server socket on a C# side and let java web service connect to that socket and send something, so C# will know when to stop?

Comment: It is a solution but i don't want to use socket into this project : /

Comment: Then call another C# web service from java web service. This new C# web service can communicate with the first C# web service.

Comment: I try to do this thing actually thanks, tell you if it work in some minutes.